# Is this a good SOA Architecture?

Tags: asp.net, .net, mobile, soa, n-tier-architecture

We are trying to re-architect our website.  Our architect came up with this high level of architecture diagram.  Is this a good architecture?[image]

Comment: People down voting my question, atleast explain why they are doing it.

Comment: "This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet." That's why I downvoted.

Comment: I actually disagree that this is unlikely to help people in the future.  This is a very common way of designing applications, and I think the question is applicable to a lot of different things.

Comment: Pity we can't downvote comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear how your MVC Model fits into the picture.  It says "Webservice Proxy" but ideally this should be hooked up to your DAL.  Is the Model simply calling the WCF services?  If so, that's sufficient, but the diagram doesn't accurately show that interaction.

I'd say otherwise that this is a good model to use and similar to ones I've used in the past.

Comment: Yes, the model simply calls the web service.

Comment: Then yes, I'd say this is solid.  The only other thing I'd say is that you probably won't have the connection string in the DAL since it's an assembly.  You'd put it in the WCF service configuration.

Comment: What about performance?  Calling all functionality through WCF a good idea for optimum performance of a website?

Comment: You sacrifice some performance for scalability, separation of concerns, and distribution, but the trade-off is worthwhile.  If all of your clients were .NET-based, you could use TCP or named-pipe binding, which would offer some performance improvements, but since you're supporting mobile apps, this isn't a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

pizza boxes! yay!  the database is drawn on its side, it should be up & down.  also, you will need a connection string in the WCF service layer as it is the entry point for the DAL layer.

i imagine you'll be starting with the MVC site, make sure to build that one using HTML5 and testing the web app on the mobile devices you plan on building clients for.  you may find that you don't need the platform specific clients at all.

Comment: WCF service calls only BLL component.  Do I still need a connection string in WCF service layer?  Also, we intend to expose a fraction of our features for mobile apps.

Comment: yes, the configuration is going to be loaded by the wcf hosting process, so that's where the connection string needs to live - the service's *.config file.

Comment: i think you can accomplish the goal of delivering a subset of features to a specific by building a single web application.  maybe not, but i would start there.  i think ultimately it will be easier & cheaper to build and maintain a single app than multiple apps on disparate platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very standard n-tier architecture and the design is so high-level that you can't really say much about it. You can find such diagram in most of the programming books that talk about n-tier architectures.

This design has nothing to do with SOA (you don't have a collection if discoverable and interconnected services), but judging from the 're-architect the website' requirement this will suffice.